# como obtener los procesos del SO con python

Tags: python, python-2.7

queria saber si hay alguna manera de hacer que python pueda saber cuales son los procesos abiertos en mi OS (win 7 en mi caso)

ej:

[tengo google abierto]

```
print "los procesos abiertos son:", procesos
```

los procesos abiertos son: google.exe

espero haberme explicado bien.
Uso python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las librerias estandar de Python no proveen dicha funcionalidad, como señala las respuesta de [*List running processes on 64-bit Windows*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/list-running-processes-on-64-bit-windows) puedes usar 2 librerias:

- [wmi](https://pypi.org/project/WMI/), solo windows

  ```
  import wmi
  c = wmi.WMI ()

  for process in c.Win32_Process ():
      print(process.ProcessId, process.Name)
  ```
- [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/), *cross platform*

  ```
  import psutil

  for p in psutil.process_iter():
      print(p, p.name(), p.pid)
  ```