# problema con wmi : ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows, windows7

ya he abierto una pregunta sobre este tema ([como obtener los procesos del SO con python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/183046/como-obtener-los-procesos-del-so-con-python/183055#183055)), el problema es que al quere usar el codigo que me dieron, que usa WMI, me muestra este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/luca/Desktop/hoja de pruebas2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wmi
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 88, in <module>
    from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida.
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Utilizo Windows 7 x64

me descarge e instale wmi desde un link de una pregunta de esta misma pagina e incluso de la pagina de microsoft pero aun asi me tira error. Gracias

Comment: ¿como has instalado la libreria? ¿has usado pip?

Comment: No me permite usar "pip" en la CMD, me lo da como un comando inexistente, incluso cuando ejecuto python desde la consola.

Comment: tienes que añadir el path de pip a las variables del sistema

Comment: uhm y como se hace eso?

Comment: en el siguiente enlace te lo indican claramente: http://lzurueta.blogspot.com/2017/07/variables-del-entorno-python-pip.html, antes de instalar con pip elimina tu instalacion de wmi anterior

Comment: gracias! lo de pywin32 tambien deberia eliminarlo?

Comment: sí, elimina todo ello porque los dlls pueden entrar en conflicto, su tienes pocas cosas instaladas te recomiendo remover todo python y reinstalarlo

Comment: vale, gracias! :D

Comment: Te aconsejo que uses `pip` como módulo ejecutando de forma explícita el intérprete en el que quieres instalar, aparte de evitar problemas que no vienen al caso es mucho más explícito y te aseguras de instalar en el intérprete adecuado, (`python -m pip install WMI` o `py -2.7 -m pip ...` si tienes varias versiones y Python launcher instalado...,) Esto hace además innecesario agregar pip al PATH y te evitas errores muy comunes si en el futuro instalas otra versión de Python (aunque lo suyo es usar entornos virtuales).

Comment: Por otro lado, el error que muestras (aparte de por instalaciones incorrectas) es muy común por instalar erróneamente paquetes de 32 bits en Python de 64 bits y viceversa, si además un paquete requiere librerías de enlace dinámico (p.e pertenecientes WMI Diagnosis Utility) estas tienen que estar compiladas para la misma arquitectura.